# How import from sql file to mysql db in ruby on rails using cloud9?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, cloud9-ide

I added file dump.sql to my project in folder db Dump volume 2,5 gb

Next my steps:

```
mysql-ctl cli 
mysql> use c9
mysql> source /home/ubuntu/workspace/myproject/db/dump.sql
```

displayed error:

```
Failed to open file '/home/ubuntu/workspace/myproject/db/dump.sql', error: 2
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the command line, change directory to whatever directory your `dump.sql` file is located in and then run:

`mysql -u username -p c9 < dump.sql`

---

Source: [Run .sql file through command line in MySQL](https://community.c9.io/t/run-sql-file-through-command-line-in-mysql/1484)